# How can I create multiple time series from one file/dataframe?

Tags: r

I'm trying to seasonally adjust over 100 times series using the 'seasonal' package. The seasonal package requires that the series be a ts object. I have a .csv file set up like so:

```
timeseriesA timeseriesB timeseriesC
obs1        obs1        obs1
obs2        obs2        obs2
.           .           .
.           .           .
```

The full file contains over 100 columns (I could also transpose the rows and columns if that's better). This lets me run the following:

```
library(seasonal)

data <- read.csv("...sa.csv")  # read csv file 

#Create time series from vectors in data
TimeSeriesA <- ts(asd$ag, start=c(1992, 1), end=c(2014, 4),frequency=4) 
TimeSeriesB <- ts(asd$cons, start=c(1992, 1), end=c(2014, 4), frequency=4) 
TimeSeriesC <- ts(asd$mfg, start=c(1992, 1), end=c(2014, 4), frequency=4) 

datalist <- list(TimeSeriesA=ag, TimeSeriesB=cons,TimeSeriesC=mfg)

#seasonally adjust the time series in datalist

ll <- lapply(datalist, function(e) try(seas(e)))

is.err <- sapply(ll, class) == "try-error"
ll[is.err]

finalsa<-do.call(cbind, lapply(ll[!is.err], final))
finalsa
```

This gives me three seasonally adjusted series, but I need 100.

I'm trying to figure out how to efficiently take my 100 series from my `.csv` file, convert them to ts in R, and put them in the list to be seasonally adjusted.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm new to R and still trying to learn it's data manipulation and transformation techniques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of the problem can be solved using `lapply()`, in the same way as for the seasonal adjustment, e.g.:

```
data <- read.csv("sa.csv")
datalist <- lapply(data, function(t) ts(t, start=c(1992, 1), end=c(2014, 4),frequency=4))
```

The seasonal adjustments should then work as described in the question.